# addin entry to -- binfmt_misc -- register file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu

I am trying to `add` an entry for an `ARM instruction interpreter` in the `binfmt_misc`.
But there is no register file in this folder /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/.

file missing : `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register`

Command to add entry :---

```
echo ':arm:M::\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x28\x00:\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfe\xff\xff\xff:/var/local/rpi/qemu/bin/qemu-arm:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

OS is `not allowing` me to create register file inside this folder binfmt_misc. Even if i try to change the access permission of for `binfmt_misc folder` inside /proc file system `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` it does not allow.

Please suggest how to add an register file inside folder binfmt_misc ?

So that i can enter name of ARM interpretter inside it.

Edit :---
I am following these two link as reference :--
http://blog.tangrs.id.au/?p=100
http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/embedded/handbook/?part=1&chap=5&style=printable
They tells how you can run arm/mips executable on diffrent linux host.

Comment: Linkin which `binfmt_misc` is defined.[1]:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java          [2]: http://wiki.luajit.org/Linux-binfmt_misc

Comment: It is Linux binfmt_misc found in the /proc directory. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 1):

[Linking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Binfmt_misc_for_Java) which [`binfmt_misc`](http://wiki.luajit.org/Linux-binfmt_misc) is defined. With The [/proc Filesystem](http://linux.startcom.org/docs/de/Introduction%20to%20Linux/x8608.html) it defined.